# Question about probability

Tags: probability

Could someone explain me how I would solve such as:

> A bag contains 6 black marbles and 2 red marbles.
>    3 marbles are picked out the bag without replacement.
>    How likely is it that you picked exactly 2 black marbles?

I know the answer is:  $0.54$ (rounded on 2 decimals).
But how would I solve questions like above?

Comment: Could you count how many different triples you can pick? And then could you count how many triples are such that they contain exactly 2 black marbles?

Comment: do you anything about combinatorics or laplace probability? where are you stuck at moment?

Comment: I've watched the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKTjh-6PFjo but in the question they pick random 3 marbels that is what confuses me I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: How would I get the answer to the question? I just happened to know the answer to the question above because it was in my textbook. But if I were to solve such question as above by myself, then I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume $3$ blanks and find the combinations, eg: **B,B,R** and you will get two more.

For **BBR**, you get $\frac{6*5*2}{8*7*6}$. Find the remaining combinations. Add them up.

This should be easy.

Comment: please use mathjax

Comment: Okay...that was my first...will keep that in mind.

Comment: @KakaS please check the edits.

Comment: @NIkunj Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hypergeometric distribution problem:

$\frac{{6 \choose 2}*{2 \choose 1}}{{8 \choose 3}}=0.5357$

From the 6 black marbles find all combinations of the picking 2 multiplied by choosing 1 red marble from the 2 available. Then divide by the total number of combinations of selecting 3 marbles from the 8 total marbles that can be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i've found an easy way for this:

> Prob(Black, Black) = (6/8)*(5/7) = 0.54 (rounded)
>
>
>   (6/8)*(5/7) = (total black / total marbles) * (total black - 1/ total marbles - 1)
>   the more precise definition would be (total black / total marbles) * (total black - n / total marbles - n)
>   where n would be the number left of each
>   this only works without replacement, since you're removing items from the stack, so to speak

Comment: while your result may be correct, your solution for sure is not. You're picking three marbles and not just two. Try to compute the probability for exactly one black marble out of three - which would be following your argument $\frac 3 4$ - but this is not the case. You can follow the answer from @Kakas